# The HTML that python requests (and urllib) is not giving the same HTML as the original

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

I am trying to create a "Price Comparison" python script. I am using '''request''' and '''Beautiful Soup''' to get the price.

But it doesn't give the same HTML as the original. I've tried to use headers, and I've tried to use urllib but still don't work.

Any help will be helpful. Thank you in advanced

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"}

response = requests.get("https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/rubiks-cube-i122835501-s127979620.html", headers=headers, timeout=5, allow_redirects=True)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

price = soup.find("span", {"class": "pdp-product-price"})

print(price) #Output is None
```

Comment: Hi Welcome to SO. What is the original HTML, what you got ?, What is the code you did? I think the question has to be improved with all this. Else it might get closed easily.

Comment: sorry I accidentally pressed Enter, I've edited the question with the original code

Comment: I think its a dynamic page and the class you are searching is auto-created with a script execution while body loads. There might be some issue that scripts are not triggered

Comment: I understand, do you have any recommendations or any alternative ways just to get the html that I need?

Answer (score 0):

To obtain the desired result you can use `selenium webdriver` in combination to `BeautifulSoup`.

Try this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="path_to_chromedriver")
driver.get("https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/rubiks-cube-i122835501-s127979620.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "lxml")
price = soup.find("span", {"class": "pdp-price"})

print(price.text) #Outp
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
₱1,250.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `selenium` for such a task as it's will completely slow down your job. you can load the `script` source and get the information. even you can use regex on `r.text` for matching `"salePrice":{"text":"₱1,250.00","value":1250}}`

However here's a very simple solution with `requests`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get(
    "https://www.lazada.com.ph/products/rubiks-cube-i122835501-s127979620.html")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json").text

price = json.loads(script)

print(price["offers"]["price"])
```